# Disable back navigation for single ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, segue

I have the following VCs:

[image: Interface Builder]

VC in the center is "Login" screen, it just redirects user to the tab bar controller, if user is authorized.

I want to disable going back to Login VC from any VC within TabBarController (with "back" button and swipe).

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for disabling both back button and swipe back feature add this lines to your viewDidLoad method:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true;
self.navigationController?.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false;
self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false;
```

Comment: Why do we have to force unwrap the fourth line and not the third? Is it because if the third line silently fails we want a crash on the fourth line? Just curious :)

Comment: Too late to be curious :D Removed it, probably copy paste leftover.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the best practice for this case is to present login view controller modally and dismiss it when user is logged in.

MainViewController.m

```
viewWillAppear{
   [super viewWillAppear];
   if (!loggedIn){
       //present login view controller
   }
}

-(void)userDidLoggedIn{//delegate called after user successfully logged in
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

And if you want to keeps this behavior then use this

Objective-C:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Swift:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Comment: But this will not disable swipe?

Comment: search for "How to disable back swipe gesture in UINavigationController on iOS 7" you will found a lot of solutions.